# Java: how can I put new object into array of objects of its class inside a constructor function? Is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, constructor

everyone! I'm total noob in Java and in programming in general and I want to implement `CarBrand` class with its' inner `Model` class (let there be no more than 4 models for each brand). For example:

```java
public class CarBrand {
  public String brand;
  public Model[4] models;
  public int curIndex = 0;
  public CarBrand(String name) {
    brand = name;
    Model[] models = new Model[4];
  }

  public class Model {
    public String modelName;
    public Model(String name) {
      modelName = name;
      models[curIndex] = this;
      curIndex = curIndex + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make new instance of `CarBrand` and its new `Model` (and add this model into `models` array of new instance of `CarBrand`) this way:

```java
public class App {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    CarBrand subaru = new Auto("Subaru");
    CarBrand.Model legacy = subaru.new Model("Legacy");
    System.out.println(subaru.models[0]);
  }
}
```

But unfortunately running `App` finishes with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot store to object array because "<parameter1>.models" is null
```

What is the reason behind that? Is there a way to add a new model in brand's `models` array? I suppose, the object wasn't created yet, that's why there is an error. How far am I from the truth?

Comment: `int[] example;` is the same as `int[] example = null;`, you never initialized your array.

Comment: @Rogue original code had
`Model[] models = new Model[4];`
in `CarBrand`'s constructor body but there is still this error. I suppose this line doesn't initialize array too?

Comment: That line you added makes a local `models` variable, but it does not assign to the field `this.models`, which is still null when (implicitly) referenced in `Model`'s constructor.

Comment: The line `public Model[4] models;` doesn’t even pass the compiler. There can’t be a `NullPointerException` with the code you’ve posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is generally incorrect: you would need

```
  public Model[] models; // not Model[4]
  public int curIndex = 0;
  public CarBrand(String name) {
    brand = name;
    models = new Model[4]; // not Model[]
  }
```